# Upload Helper Codeigniter problems. No upload the image

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, frameworks

No image being upload what am I'm doing wrong with the Upload Helper CodeIgniter. It's driving me crazy.

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('http://work/npanel/users/save'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Name'); ?>
    <?php 

    $data_name = array(
      'name' => 'name',
      'class' => 'form-control',
    );

    echo form_input($data_name);
    ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Lastname'); ?>
    <?php 

    $data_lastname = array(
      'name' => 'lastname',
      'class' => 'form-control',
    );

    echo form_input($data_lastname);
    ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_label('Picture'); ?>
    <?php

    $data_upload = array(
      'type' => 'file',
      'name' => 'image'
    );
    echo form_upload($data_upload);
    ?>
</div>

<?php
$data_hidden = array(
  'id' => $id
);

echo form_hidden($data_hidden);
?>

<?php
$send = array(
  'class' =>'btn-primary',
  'type' =>'submit',
  'value' =>'Save'
);

echo form_submit($send);
?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function save($name, $lastname, $id, $image)
{
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $image = $this->input->post('image');

    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $last_id = $this->User_model->save($name, $lastname, $id, $image);

    $config['upload_path'] = '/assets/img/users/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload("image");
    $t = $this->upload->data;

    $this->load->model('Images_model');
    $this->Images_model->setImage($t, $last_id);

    redirect('http://work.com/npanel/users');
}
```

Does not save image 'assets / img / users' folder and does not generate the file name. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you have used `http` inside form action. it should be `controller_name/action_name` same as redirect.
Why you are passing parameter in `save function`. Is your request posted in `save function`?

Comment: Remove starting slashed and try `
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/users/';`

Comment: AH Jebbon - I've tried it both ways. Using http and as Controller> action. It was a test. It does not work that way. So what happens or not I'm doing wrong.

Comment: devpro - 
it does not work. I have made changes but still does not save or display the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On view on your form_open_multipart('users/save') you only need the controller name and function

You can use form validation if you want to http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Make sure you have set your base_url in config.php

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://work/npanel/';
```

Controller function

Filename Users.php first letter upper case only

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {    

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('images_model');
    }

    public function save($name,$lastname,$id,$image) {     
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $image = $this->input->post('image');   

        $last_id = $this->user_model->save($name, $lastname, $id, $image);

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/users/';
        //$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . '/assets/img/users/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size']    = '2048';

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $this->upload->do_upload("image");

        $t = $this->upload->data; 

        $this->images_model->setImage($t['file_name'], $last_id);

        redirect('users/save');     

    }

}
```

On view your forum open should only controller name and function you can also put folder name if in folder

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('users/save'); ?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('if_in_folder_name/users/save'); ?>
```

Comment: It worked. My patch is

Use the and it worked. Thank you very much to all.

Comment: @NicolasMaximowicz don't forget to vote up or accept answer